# tomcat and his classpath manager

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat6

if deploy on tomcat myapp.war contains two lib (lib1.jar and lib2.jar), which contain both a.b.c.MyObj

which one chooses at the time of the creation of MyObj ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior is not predictable. The class loader loads the first properly named class it finds in the classpath and effectively "hides" all other properly named classes.

Look at this [tip](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javatips/jw-javatip105.html) from javaworld which references a tool named JWhich to help in these scenarios.